# PHP QR Code outputting .png as a character string

Tags: php, wordpress

I've built my first WordPress plugin to create a QR Code from a form.

It's just for learning purposes and would not meet standards for commercial release.

However it works perfectly on my local server in WAMP using Twenty Twenty theme.

When i test it on my live site (with a commercial theme) the qr code in .png format is displayed as a atring of characters similar to this.

`�PNG  IHDR{{n m<�PLTE���U��~ pHYs���+aIDATH���1�� ��P��H�W�]���� �΂0;>_�n�ζ�X����w����h�`

The string is much longer, but i just put a snippet in to show what i mean.

Below is my plugin code and it includes the full untouched phpqrcode library.

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: QR Code Generator
 * Plugin URI: https://www.example.com/qr-code-generator
 * Description: A plugin that allows you to easily generate QR codes for use on your website.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Your Name
 * Author URI: https://www.example.com
 * License: GPL2
 */
include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php' );

function qr_code_shortcode( $atts ) {
    // Extract the attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'text' => '',
    ), $atts ) );
 
    global $post;
 
    // Check if the shortcode is present in the post or page
    if ( has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'qr_code' ) ) {
        // Check if the form has been submitted
        if ( isset( $_POST['qr_code_text'] ) ) {
            $text = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['qr_code_text'] );
            // Generate the QR code
            QRcode::png( $text );
        } else {
            // Display the form
            ob_start();
            echo '<form method="post">';
            echo '<label for="qr_code_text">Enter the text for the QR code:</label><br>';
            echo '<input type="text" name="qr_code_text" id="qr_code_text"><br>';
            echo '<input type="submit" value="Generate QR Code">';
            echo '</form>';
            return ob_get_clean();
        }
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'qr_code', 'qr_code_shortcode' );
```

Any suggestions as to why it would work in one site and not on another ?

I've tried using base64 on the image thinking it was that but to no avail.